# Nginx configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

When I run

```
sudo mate /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
```

my nginx.conf file opens but is blank, what did i do wrong?

trying to deploy my rails app to a ubuntu 10.04 lucid with passenger, nginx, and REE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On which machine are you running "sudo mate ..."? If you're trying to deploy, you should be on the Ubuntu server. I suspect you're using a Mac for development and the command you've issued is to edit the local nginx installation on your Mac, not on the deployment server.

Comment: nice yeah, this is the first time deploying a rails app, hosting with linode, etc. total rookie. what command should i issue to make sure im on the ubuntu server?

Comment: i was running `sudo mate` from my root/home directory

Answer (score 1):

You can check where you are with command:

```
$ uname -a
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're not looking for:

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

on your server?